# Heroku we're sorry but something went wrong on single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So im trying to deploy and app to heroku.  everything works fine except for one page which yields the error
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

it seems like a pretty common problem yet i havent found any solution.  even after trying rake:db migrate i havent gotten it to work.  here the code for the page in question.

Thanks!

_discussion.html.erb

```
<% content_for :script do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'hover_content' %>
<% end %>

<% @micropost = Micropost.new %>
<% @micropost.discussion_id = discussion.id %>

<li>
  <div class = "intro-bar"><span class = "intro"><%=discussion.intro %></span></div>
  <div class = "content-bar">
    <span class = "content"><%= discussion.content %></span>
  </div>
  <input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
    <div class = "buttons">
      <!--<div class = "vote-neg"><%= link_to "Break Up", signup_path,class: "btn btn-large btn-breakup" %></div>-->
      <!--<div class = "vote-plus"><%= link_to "Stay Together", signup_path,class: "btn btn-large btn-staytogether" %></div>-->
    </div>

</li>

<span class = "timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(discussion.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>

            <% if signed_in? %>
                <div class = "row">
                  <aside class = "span4">
                    <section>
                      <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
                          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
                          <div class="field">
                            <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post a comment" %>
                          </div>
                          <%= f.hidden_field :discussion_id%>

                          <%= f.submit "Break Up", class: "btn btn-large btn-breakup",:name => "break_up" %>
                          <%= f.submit "Stay Together", class: "btn btn-large btn-staytogether", :name => "stay_together" %>
                              <% end %>
                              </section>
                              </aside>
                              </div>
                          <% end %>

<div class = "comments">
  <% discussion.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
      <div class = 'comment-box'>
      <li>
        <div class = "comment-pic"></div>
        <div class = "post-comment"><%= micropost.content%></div>
      </li>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

heroku logs

```
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (hover_content.js isn't precompiled):
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: 
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% content_for :script do %>
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'hover_content' %>
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <% end %>
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: 
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <% @micropost = Micropost.new %>
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126695+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/discussions/_discussion.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_discussions__discussion_html_erb__4373186011715748050_22056420'
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126926+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/discussions/_discussion.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_discussions__discussion_html_erb__4373186011715748050_22056420'
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126926+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/discussions/index.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_discussions_index_html_erb__565682135676542669_24344900'
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126926+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/discussions/index.html.erb:4:in `each'
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126926+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/discussions/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_discussions_index_html_erb__565682135676542669_24344900'
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126926+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T20:23:26.126926+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T20:23:26.168750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/discussions host=stage-breakupornot.herokuapp.com fwd="74.92.136.101" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=196ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Comment: Have you seen what is the output of `heroku logs`?

Comment: how exactly do i run the logs to let me see the source of the issue?

Comment: `heroku logs --tail` use that and look for rails errors

Comment: Is this answer helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8816316/1004046

Comment: Looks like [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) issues.

Comment: rake assets:precompile

then you push

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as others in the comments mentioned, that your javascript resource is not precompiled.

The solution is a little bit more than just making sure you precompile the assets, which by the way heroku will do when you push so you don't have to.

The problem lies in that you are doing this:

```
<% content_for :script do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'hover_content' %>
<% end %>
```

Since you are referencing hover_content directly instead of just including it in your application.js then you must tell Rails that you want this included in the asset precompile step.

Modify your production.rb file and add this line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( hover_content.js )
```

That will tell rails that in addition to the application.js which automatically gets compiled and included that you want to also include this other file hover_content.js